# Parse youtube links with feedjira

Tags: ruby-on-rails, feedjira

I use rails 5.2, feedjira 2.1.0

If I parse youtube link

I have this error:

**undefined method `image' for #Feedjira::Parser::AtomYoutubeEntry:0x00007fa14be348d0**

other links work

my code:

```
def self.add_entries(entries, stream_id)
      entries.each do |entry|
          unless  FeedEntry.where(guid: entry.id).exists?
            FeedEntry.create!(
              :name          => entry.title,
              :url           => entry.url,
              :summary       => entry.summary,
              :published_at  => entry.published,
              :enclosure_url => entry.image,
              :enclosure_type => entry.enclosure_type,
              :guid          => entry.id,
              :source_id => stream_id
            )
          end
      end
end
```

**How to make to parse all links?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting an image attribute but there is no attribute called image in AtomYoutubeEntry.

Have a look at [Feedjira on github](https://github.com/feedjira/feedjira/blob/master/lib/feedjira/parser/atom_youtube_entry.rb). There is for example a `media_thumbnail_url` which you could use.

Comment: How to leave the image attribute for other links?

Comment: You have to check the specific entry if it has an image attribute or an other attribute.